# C# CS1502: Best Overloaded Match not finding the correct function in the docs

Tags: c#, .net, mono

I am working with the C# Mono Compiler and the complier keeps giving me the CS1502 error due to not being able to find the correct function in the Docs. Specifically, I am getting problems with the Split function in the String API with the following message

```
The best overloaded method match for `string.Split(params char[])' has some invalid arguments
```

when I am trying to use the Split(String[], StringSplitOptions)  function outlined on this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx

, which is found in the API documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx

**Edit:** The piece of code I am trying to write is this:

```
words = line.Split("\t");
```

I am trying to split a tab-separated String (the variable '*line*') into an array of strings '*words*'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the tab (`\t`) as a `char` not a `string` using enclosing single quotes vs. double quotes, i.e.:

```
words = line.Split('\t');
```

Comment: @lorkaan double check that you are only including a single char, `\t`

Comment: I originally used 

`words = reader.ReadLine().Split('\t');`
where reader is a StreamReader Object

but it keeps giving me this error:
`error CS1012: Too many characters in character literal`

Comment: @lorkaan Make sure you do not have any hidden Unicode characters (i.e. delete and retype the line), as the code line `reader.ReadLine().Split('\t')` is correct

Comment: Thanks so much, turns out there was a hidden character or something so I deleted the line and rewrote it and it works now.